# Why do I get this error when running KNN model in R caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)

# Load 2 dimensional data
ring <- mlbench.ringnorm(1000, d=2)


trControl <- trainControl(method  = "cv",
                          number  = 5)

fit <- train(ring$x ~ .,
             method     = "knn",
             tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 1:10),
             trControl  = trControl,
             metric     = "Accuracy",
             data       = ring)
```

I am trying to run knn (using cross-validation as the performance metric) on the data, using different values of k (1 to 10) to classify.

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in data[0, cols, drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You model a 2 dimensional outcome by typing `ring$x ~ .`, because `ring$x` has 2 columns. However, the outcome must be just one column.

You can transform the matrix to a `data.frame` to have column names to work with:

```
data <- data.frame(ring$x)
## A tibble: 1,000 × 2
#       X1     X2
#    <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 -1.26   2.39 
# 2 -0.598  1.95 

fit <- train(
  x = data[,-1],
  y = data$X1,
  method     = "knn",
  tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = 1:10),
  trControl  = trControl,
  metric     = "Accuracy",
  data       = data
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas why the following error comes up even though column names have been specified? `Please use column names for x.`

Comment: @HelpMe, for that error you should use `train(data[predictors], data[[outcomeName]]`